# Using offset in SQL to count column or sum is empty in postgresql

Tags: sql, postgresql

Using PostgreSQL 10.6 (RedHat)

When I am using this SQL to sum or count data like this

```
select count(1) 
from test 
limit 10
```

it also returns the all data count?

If I am using this SQL:

```
select count(1) 
from test 
offset 10 limit 10 ;  --  return empty
```

or this SQL:

```
select sum(some_column) 
from test 
offset 10 limit 10 -- return empty
```

I am surprised.

Comment: Those queries return 1 row each, without OFFSET. With OFFSET 10 you try to read 11'th row etc.

Comment: @jarlh my table data have least 4w

Comment: `select count(*)` returns **exactly** one row. Applying a limit or offset on that query makes no sense. If you are trying to sum "the first 10 rows", then use something like: `select sum(some_column) from (select come_column from test order by something limit 10) t`

Comment: 4w? The count(1) quer returns the number of rows in a table, that's one single row. SUM does the similar.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

What is confusing?  An aggregation query with no `group by` *always* returns one row.

If you try to take the first ten rows . . . well, you get the one row.

If you try to take the eleventh row . . . well, there is none.